# How to create and print list of sub arrays out of one long array

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have a long array of strings that will have a varying length because I'm pulling the strings from a database table that will be filled dynamically by user submission, however, that long array will be comprised of a repeating set of 6 variables. So I want to slice it at every 6th index, turning what I've sliced into an array, and then printing the list of those sub arrays to the page. 
This is what I have so far:

```
//I'm using Parse as my database and the find() method is one way you query it. 

var search = [];

query.find({
  success: function(results) {

//loop through results to get the key-value pair of each row

    for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++){

    activity = results[i].get("activity");
    scene = results[i].get("location");
    neighborhood = results[i].get("neighborhood");
    date = results[i].get("date");
    details = results[i].get("details");
    time = results[i].get("time");

    //Here I'm pushing the row of the six variables into an array, but since there will be multiple rows on the table from multiple submissions, the array will contain however many rows there are. 

        search.push(activity, scene, neighborhood, date, details, time);

    //my second array

         var search2 = [];

    //This is that part I'm unsure of. I want to loop through the search array slicing it at every 6th index creating multiple sub arrays. I then want to write the list of those sub arrays to the page

    for(i=0; i < search.length; i+=6){
        search2 = search.slice(0,6);
      }

//this is the div I want to write the arrays to. 
     $("#mainDiv").text(search2);

    };// closes success function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of pushing each individual field onto the search array and then slicing each set out at the end, why don't you just add each record's set of data as an array to your search array?

```
search.push([activity, scene, neighborhood, date, details, time]);
```

That way, when you loop through the search array to print out each record's values you don't have to do any slicing or incrementing by 6.  For each loop you already have the array slice you want:

```
for (i = 0; i < search.length; i++) {
    $('#mainDiv').append(search[i]);
}
```

Maybe I've misread your question, but it looks like you want to add all the records to your #mainDiv.  If you use the jQuery text() method for each iteration of your loop, you'll just overwrite the text for each iteration, making the result the final value of your loop instead of all of the values of all of the items.  To add each record to your #mainDiv, you want to use the append() method.

You might also want to add some spaces between the values, assuming you are using my approach to storing sets of arrays instead of individual field array items:

```
for (i = 0; i < search.length; i++) {
    $('#mainDiv').append(search[i].join(' '));
}
```